# C# Дана строка символов. Подсчитать самую длинную последовательность подряд идущих букв а

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Дана строка символов. Подсчитать самую длинную последовательность подряд идущих букв а.( P.S. напишите полную программу попроще. С# знаю плохо)

Comment: Вам не Фриланс или Решалку. За деньги вам сделают всё что угодно

Comment: Один цикл, один счетчик, два условия. Чтобы чему-то научиться, надо научиться прикладывать усилия.

Answer (score 1):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##VU9NC8IwDL33V0QvtmwWPZcJ4knQkwfPodat4DpsOlHE3z5Th6A55OPlvRdiaW7JD0NPPtRweFByrRG/k975cDVC3DACQQVTRDoRIeaKfzGin5iyYtMF6i5OH6NPjl2cJL2u6@hqTE7KRQkLVYKMjkqwjYJqBU8BkA/JFu@l7SODwHvDsD@DtA1MKpjhTDGa@hhGIvtkRlGwIjff3R5To/d4H0nZbsxGvJTe8m9LZYbhDQ)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

var s = "aasdssaaaasdaaaaaaaaaaaaaassaaaaaaaaa";

Console.WriteLine(s.Aggregate((0, 0), (res, ch) => {
  var (max,cur) = res;
  if (ch != 'a') return (max, 0);
  ++cur;
  return (Math.Max(max, cur), cur);
}).Item1);
```

```
14
```

Comment: Ахахах! :) отлично, правда я бы регулярок досыпал.

Comment: Во `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(s, "a+").Max(m => m.Value.Length));`

Comment: @aepot, а чего не ответом?)

Comment: Так вопроса как бы нет. Дарю, можете к себе утащить.

Comment: думаю один из лучших из возможных ответов в даной ситуации)